# Ошибка THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, three.js

Перешел на webpack. Импортирую **three.js** так:

```
 import THREELib from "three-js";
 const THREE = THREELib();
```

Использую  es6 модули:

```
 export default class MyModule {
   ....
 }

 static myGeometry() {
   return new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(MyModule.getShape());
 }
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry is not a constructor

В чем может быть проблема? `ShapeBufferGeometry`, вроде, видит.

Answer (score 0):

твоя версия либы устарела, просто стяни последний Three.js и обнови.